# Flutter Redux and Hook. How to watch variable instance changing inside useEffect like react?

Tags: flutter, redux, hook

Im new in flutter and trying to watch a variable "count "that is in state of reducer like React native. I made my redux and hook work perfeclty. The variable count change in the screen but never call useEffect again(only once) event if i change de action. Tried diferente aproachs without success and tried to put StoreProvider.of(context).state.balanceState.count directly in the dependecis of useEffect. If i use useState works like should.

```
class StatePage extends HookWidget {
  const StatePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);   


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    int count = StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context).state.balanceState.count;



    useEffect(() {

      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) =>
          StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context).dispatch(getBalanceThunk()));
    }, [count]);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ola'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StoreConnector<AppState, BalanceState>(
          converter: (store) => store.state.balanceState,
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                if (state.loading)
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                Text(state.message),
                Text(count.toString()),
                RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Clicar'),
                    onPressed: (){
                      StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context).dispatch(SetCountAction(count++));
                    })
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my Action

```
abstract class BalanceAction {}


class BalanceStateAction  extends BalanceAction {
    final bool loading;
    final bool error;
    final String message;
    BalanceStateAction(this.loading, this.error, this.message);
}

class SetBalanceAction  extends BalanceAction {
    final double value;
    SetBalanceAction(this.value);
}

class SetCountAction  extends BalanceAction {
    final int count;

    SetCountAction(this.count);
}
```

my Reducer

```
import 'package:flutter_red_test/redux/actions/balance_action.dart';

class BalanceState {
  final bool loading;
  final bool error;
  final String message;
  final double value;
  final int count;


  BalanceState({
    this.loading = false,
    this.count = 0,
    this.error = false,
    this.message = '',
    this.value = null,
  });

  factory BalanceState.initialState(){
    return BalanceState(
      loading: false,
      error: false,
      message: '',
      value: null,
      count: 0,
    );
  }

  BalanceState copy({bool loading, bool error, String message, double value, int count}){
    return BalanceState(
        loading: loading ?? this.loading,
        error: error ?? this.error,
        message: message ?? this.message,
        value: value ?? this.value,
      count: count ?? this.count,
    );
  }
}

BalanceState balanceReducer(BalanceState state, BalanceAction action){
        if(action is BalanceStateAction){
          return state.copy(
              loading: action.loading,
              message: action.message,
              value: state.value,
              error: action.error,
            count: state.count,
          );
        }
        if(action is SetBalanceAction){
          return state.copy(
            loading: false,
            message: 'Seu saldo é de 20.000',
            value: action.value,
            count: state.count,
            error: false,
          );
        }
        if(action is SetCountAction){
          return state.copy(
            loading: false,
            message: state.message,
            value: state.value,
            count: action.count,
            error: false,
          );
        }
      return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this issue: https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/244

> This library does not support flutter hooks out of the box, since it
> is a 3rd party package in the Flutter ecosystem. This library is only
> built to work with flutter + redux.
>
> Please see alternative packages, such as
> https://pub.dev/packages/redux_hooks to get that functionality!